# get and change attributes of has_and_belongs_to_many [rails4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, schema

I am following the rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html to make a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation between the user and event while in the table `users_events` I have another attributes like `admin:boolean` and timestamps.

When the user create the event I want that the boolean be true, while other users participate into that event the `admin` boolean will be false.

*How can I assign values to these attributes?*

```
users_events table
---------------------
t.references :user
t.references :event
t.boolean :admin
t.timestamps
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to use the `has_many :through` association instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

This way you will be able to create the `UserEvent` manually to assign your attributes.

More details on: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: Hi jvenezia, that was my previous solution, but couldn't assign the attributes. How can I use UserEvent?

Comment: Just make it an ActiveRecord Model, like any other. Then you could UserEvent.create(user_id: user.id, event_id: event.id, admin: true)